# Getting coefficients of a cubic spline from scipy.interpolate.splrep

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am doing a cubic spline interpolation using scipy.interpolate.splrep as following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.sin(x)

tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, task=0, s=0)
F   = scipy.interpolate.PPoly.from_spline(tck)
```

I print t and c:

```
print F.x

array([  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
     2.22222222,   3.33333333,   4.44444444,   5.55555556,
     6.66666667,   7.77777778,  10.        ,  10.        ,
    10.        ,  10.        ])

print F.c

array([[ -1.82100357e-02,  -1.82100357e-02,  -1.82100357e-02,
     -1.82100357e-02,   1.72952212e-01,   1.26008293e-01,
     -4.93704109e-02,  -1.71230879e-01,  -1.08680287e-01,
      1.00658224e-01,   1.00658224e-01,   1.00658224e-01,
      1.00658224e-01],
   [ -3.43151441e-01,  -3.43151441e-01,  -3.43151441e-01,
     -3.43151441e-01,  -4.64551679e-01,   1.11955696e-01,
      5.31983340e-01,   3.67415303e-01,  -2.03354294e-01,
     -5.65621916e-01,   1.05432909e-01,   1.05432909e-01,
      1.05432909e-01],
   [  1.21033389e+00,   1.21033389e+00,   1.21033389e+00,
      1.21033389e+00,  -5.84561936e-01,  -9.76335250e-01,
     -2.60847433e-01,   7.38484392e-01,   9.20774403e-01,
      6.63563923e-02,  -9.56285846e-01,  -9.56285846e-01,
     -9.56285846e-01],
   [ -4.94881722e-18,  -4.94881722e-18,  -4.94881722e-18,
     -4.94881722e-18,   7.95220057e-01,  -1.90567963e-01,
     -9.64317117e-01,  -6.65101515e-01,   3.74151231e-01,
      9.97097891e-01,  -5.44021111e-01,  -5.44021111e-01,
     -5.44021111e-01]])
```

So I had supplied the x array as :

```
array([  0.        ,   1.11111111,   2.22222222,   3.33333333,
     4.44444444,   5.55555556,   6.66666667,   7.77777778,
     8.88888889,  10.        ])
```

Q.1: The F.x (knots) are not the same as original x array and has duplicate values (possibly to force first derivative to zero?). Also some values in x (1.11111111, 8.88888889) are missing in F.x. Any ideas?

Q.2 The shape of F.c is (4, 13). I understand that 4 comes from the fact that it is cubic spline fit. But I do not know how do I select coefficients for each of the 9 sections that I want (from x = 0 to x=1.11111, x = 1.111111 to x = 2.222222 and so on). Any help in extraction of the coefficients for different segments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have the knots in specific locations along the curves you need to use the argument `task=-1` of `splrep` and give an array of **interior** knots as the `t` argument.

The knots in `t` must satisfy the following condition:

> If provided, knots t must satisfy the Schoenberg-Whitney conditions, i.e., there must be a subset of data points x[j] such that t[j] < x[j] < t[j+k+1], for j=0, 1,...,n-k-2.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep).

Then you should get `F.c` of the following size `(4, <length of t> + 2*(k+1)-1)` corresponding to the consecutive intervals along the curve (`k+1` knots are added at either end of the curve by `splrep`).

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
y = np.sin(x)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y, t=t[1:-1])

F   = scipy.interpolate.PPoly.from_spline(tck)

print(F.x)
print(F.c)

# Accessing coeffs of nth segment: index = k + n - 1
# Eg. for second segment:
print(F.c[:,4])
```

Comment: I did the following: tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, Y, s=0, t=x). However, I get error on this as: tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, Y, s=0, t=x)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 515, in splrep
    raise _iermess[ier][1](_iermess[ier][0])
ValueError: Error on input data

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see any hint of 'choosing' knots there. Any reference on this would be helpful.

Comment: Amended answer to give more info about the `t` array and added an example. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies a lot.

Comment: I added how to access a segment's coefficients too. I trust this is correct and answers both your questions.